# Aggregating data by grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to create a new variable/column in a data frame at the county level from the mean variable of viral fragments detected in municipalities within this specific county for each day municipalities reported data. I have been able to calculate this mean with two different ways the following code:

```
dataframe[, mean(SARS.mean), by = date]
aggregate(datframeme$SARS.mean, list(dataframe$Date.Collected), FUN=mean)
```

but when i do something like

```
dataframe$countymeanforeachday <- dataframe[, mean(SARS.mean), by = date]
dataframe$countymeanforeachday <- aggregate(datframeme$SARS.mean, list(dataframe$Date.Collected), FUN=mean)
```

it does not work. Please advise I beg

Comment: `datframeme <- transform(datframeme, countymeanforeachday = ave(SARS.mean, Date.Collected, FUN = mean))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  group_by(Date.Collected) %>%
  mutate(countymeanforeachday = mean(SARS.mean, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```